# PDF generation getting error on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

This same code is working in my local machine because of I am with running this code through VS2015 IDE but when I published it to IIS getting below error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The remote server returned an error:
>   (404) Not Found.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.   Exception Details: System.Net.WebException:
>   The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Source Error:
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>   Stack Trace:  [WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (404) Not Found.]    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8420880 
>   iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url) +109
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.ElementFactory.CreateImage(String
>   src, IDictionary`2 attrs, ChainedProperties chain, IDocListener
>   document, IImageProvider img_provider, Dictionary`2 img_store, String
>   img_baseurl) +388
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.CreateImage(IDictionary`2
>   attrs) +448
>
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLTagProcessor_IMG.StartElement(HTMLWorker
>   worker, String tag, IDictionary`2 attrs) +113
>   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.StartElement(String tag,
>   IDictionary`2 attrs) +127
>   iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader reader)
>   +1334    Therasmart.admin.InvoicePdf.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +675    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

My code is as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (GetTherepistDetails() == "success" && GetInvoice() == "success" && GetClientDetails() == "success")
                {

                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoice.pdf");
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                    var sw = new StringWriter();
                    var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
                    var sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                    var pdfDoc = new Document();
                    pdfDoc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                    var htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                    pdfDoc.Open();

                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

                    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "alert('Getting error in Invoice generation copy has been sent.');", true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help to resolve this.